# How do I remove the pound signs on OUTLINE for markdown files

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

How do I remove the pound signs on OUTLINE for markdown files?
And the `abc` as well :)

[image]

EDIT: I found how to remove the `abc`.

```
"outline.icons": false
```